# With Sequelize bulkUpdate inside a migration can I access `this` to generate value?

Tags: sequelize.js

In Sequelize you can `bulkUpdate` records inside a migration. But I want to generate a @handle attribute using the values of the fullName attribute. Is there a way to access the record I'm updating (like `this`) something like this:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkUpdate('users', { handle: this.fullName.replace(/\s+/g, '') });
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('roles', null, {});
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`bulkUpdate` doesn't have model instances to update them. It generates `UPDATE` SQL-query to execute against DB so you need to use DB functions to replace some substring with another one in each record that will be updated. Such functions can highly depend on a certain type of DBMS so look at the DBMS documentation on how to achieve such replacement.
It might look like this:

```js
queryInterface.bulkUpdate('users', {
  handle: Sequelize.fn('replace', Sequelize.col('fullName'), 'substring to be replaced', 'substring to use as a replcement')
})
```

It's not guaranteed that your DBMS supports regular expressions in a function used to replace a.substring.